# How do I return back to the first collectionview cell item?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicolor

I'm working in `UICollectionViewCell` for my mobile app. When you tap the `crossBtn` it should go to the first `UICollectionViewCell` with reloading the data but `collectionView?.reloadData()` makes the colours messed up and it doesn't stay to one colour at a time per cell. Instead it keeps showing multiple colours on the cells even though I've put the colour as `UIColor.clear` in `didDeselectItemAt` method.

How do I return back to the first `UICollectionViewCell` item when the user taps on `crossBtn` without reloading the whole `UICollectionView`?

```
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filters.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.hamburgerLabel.text = filters[indexPath.item]

//        cell.hamburgerImageView.image = filterImages[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    setFilter(title: filterNames[indexPath.row])
    toolBar.isHidden = true
    yesAndNoToolBar.isHidden = false
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}


@IBAction func crossBtn(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    toolBar.isHidden = false
    yesAndNoToolBar.isHidden = true

    collectionView?.reloadData()

    let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.last ?? IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredVertically)

}
```

Comment: Use `scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)` to scroll to the first index path

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesn't work without using: 'collectionView?.reloadData()' which messes with the collectionview cell items so they have multiple selections which I don't want to do.

Comment: scrolling to an indexPath does not require reloading the collection view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have to reload the data. You can use the following method to scroll to a given index path.

```
let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.last ?? IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
func scrollToItem(at indexPath: indexPath, 
               at scrollPosition: .centeredVertically, 
         animated: true)
```

Note that this is different from using `selectItem(at:animated:scrollPosition:)`.

Also, you should set the colours etc that you are having trouble with in the `cellForItem` method, not in the selection and deselection delegate methods. This is because cells are reused, so the cell you are styling will be used in a different place when you scroll. Instead, use the selection and deselection methods to store the selected index path(s) in a variable (or array of multiple), then check this array in `cellForItem` to determine whether to apply selected styling to that cell. This is why `collectionView.reloadData()` messes things up for you!